# ffmpeg c++ добавление кадров к существующему потоку

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

Всем привет! Описание процесса и проблемы:
При помощи библиотеки ffmpeg из сети получаю медиа-поток с данными (видео, аудио и так далее). Из потока копируются все необходимые контексты и прочее, и далее пакеты записывается в файл методом `av_interleaved_write_frame`. Все работет как надо, то есть файл создается, данные записываются, потом все корректно и правильно отображается в любом проигрывателе, то есть ремюксинг работает.

**Вопрос.** При отсутствии данных, точнее при временном разрыве соединения необходимо в файл добавлять кадры-заглушки (обычные видеокадры с какой-нибудь надписью) с частотой потока.
Я уже кое-что сделал, но пока оно не работает.

Может быть кто-нибудь подкинет мысль как это делается "по-правильному"? Спасибо

Comment: Вам стоит начать принимать видео поток разделяя его по группам изображений (GOP), при обнаружении дырки в полученной группе отбрасывать ее заменяя ее группой с кадрами - заглушками.

Comment: А если просто добавить ещё один источник (статический кадр), а поверх него накладывать видео, не прокатит?

Comment: @Qwertiy - задачу решил полгода назад, сейчас пишу ответ. Немного терпения )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задачу решил поэтому дам ответ. Будем говорить об видеопотоке, потому что со всеми остальными (звуковым, текстовым, данных) все проще.

Есть два подхода один из которых для меня остался теоретическим с него и начну.

**Теотерический**
Медиаданные в потоке сжаты соответствующим алгоритмом (кодеком), поэтому при получении первых живых данных вы получаете также и соответствующие алгоритмы (их названия, сами кодеки должны быть установлены в системе заранее) и в случае потери соединения теоретически вы можете добавлять в ваше устройство вывода кадры-заглушки, которые необходимо сжимать именно сетевым кодеком (повторю; который, конечно должен быть предварительно установлен в системе). Возникающие проблемы, это учет связанности кадров в потоке по общей схеме IPBB (в частности B - кадры, содержащие сведения из кадров до себя и после), нумерация кадров и так далее. К сожалению был ограничен во времени, поэтому получив проблемы "подмешивания" и не сумев  их решить оперативно, перешел ко второму методу

**Практический**
 В данном подходе все намного проще, но нагрузки для системы больше. Вы создаете свой формат (в парадигме ffmpeg - другие контексты, то есть потоки, другие кодеки и так далее), выбираете произвольно любой подходящий кодек (который может случайно совпасть с входным, но это не суть)  расжимаете входной поток (кадры входного потока) потоковыми кодеками и перекодирутете "своими". При разрыве соединения вы берете кадры-заглушки (любое изображение) и загоняете их в свое устройство вывода используя "свои" приготовленные ранее кодеки. Нумерация кадров в данном методе сквозная, проблем с IPBB не возникает. Единственный минус дополнительная нагрузка на систему, так как выполняется "необязательное" декодирование входного потока и перекодирование в ваш формат.